# javascript create element not working in electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I am trying to make an application in electron. What it does is that it takes the names of image files from a json file and loads it in the app. But it does not seem to be working.

This is my javascript code:

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
            callback(rawFile.responseText);
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}


readTextFile("/home/kevin/my-electron-app/data/covers/covers.json", function(text){
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    for (index in data) {
    
        
        let cover_name = data[index]
        for (indexA in cover_name) {
            cover_nameA = cover_name[indexA]
            
            var imageContainerDiv = document.createElement("div");
            var coverImage = document.createElement("img");
            coverImage.setAttribute("src", "data/covers/" + cover_nameA)
            coverImage.setAttribute("class", "imageRight")
            imageContainerDiv.appendChild(coverImage)
            console.log(coverImage)
        }
    }
});
```

as you can see I first create an image element then give it the src attribute and the class attribute and then put it inside the div.

But when I start the application the images don't load. If I copy the image tag from the console and paste it in the html file, the image loads but it won't load like this.

I am trying for hours now and I can't get it to work. I am new to electron (just started yesterday) so I don't know a lot.

this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome.min.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;**script-src 'self' http://onlineerp.solution.quebec 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';** ">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <p class="title">Library</p>
    </header>
    <section>
      <p class="dontShow">This is just a p tag</p>
      
      <script type="text/json" id="coversJson" src="data/covers/covers.json"></script>
      
    </section>
    <footer>

      <button class="libraryButton"><i class="fas fa-book-open"></i></button>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
.title {
    text-align: left;
    color: rgb(235, 159, 235);
    font-size: 20px;
}

body {
    background-color: rgba(22, 24, 24, 0.966);
}

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    
}
.libraryButton {
    position: relative; 
    width: 45px; 
    height: 45px;
    top: 100;
}
.imageContainer {
    padding: 15px;
}
.imageRight {
    width: 175px;
    height: 225px;
   
}
.imageLeft {
    width: 175px;
    height: 225px;
    
}
.dontShow {
    display: none;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You've to insert `imageContainerDiv` to the DOM to see it.

Comment: Where exactly do you want insert the divs? You can use `appendChild` similarly you've inserted the image to the div.

Comment: @Teemu thank you very much. I appended it to the section element in my html file and it finally worked!